# Slide Up Visible Sub Reports in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, removing-whitespace, slideup

I have an SSRS Report composed off datasets (tablixes) and subreports. How do I have the reports slide up when they are visible.

```
Report 
A (NOT visible)
B (visible)
C (NOT visible)
D (NOT visible)
E (visible)
```

Visibility is set based on user input/parameters, etc. In the above example what will appear on screen is the tablix B / sub-report E. How I want it to appear is with out extra white space which it now has.

or in another scenario they could just pick E which is common and now we get a lot of white space at the top. What setting do I pick, what code can i write to have the visible rectangle of data slide up to the very top of available space.

So all we see is

```
Report
B
E
```

or

```
Report 
E
```

Comment: Create parameter and pass the values of report ids. Use that parameter in tablixes visibility formula.

Comment: Yes, that I am doing. The question is not how to set up visibility but how to get the visible ones to slide up so the report doesn't have awkward white space.

Comment: 1. You can insert empty table with 1 column and multiple rows. 2. delete the groups. 3. Then inside the rows put the reports. 4. Set the row visibility. 5. Set TextBox can grow property is true.

Answer (score 1):

When you've placed subreports on your page, did you make whitespaces between them? I belive you did. And now, when you hide one of subreport, whitespaces still visible and accumulate. You should reorganize your page by insert rectangles one below the other without (or minimum) whitespaces between of them. Put your subreports into each rectangle and add whitespaces inside it. Change expressions to control rectangles visibility instead subreports.

Don't forget: in spite of subreport is hidden, it is still retriving data and loads your server. To avoid it, pass visibility status to your subreports, to tell thems datasets to select null.

P.S. If you see extra white space in preview mode, it is not allways the same as browser will display. Especially if you hide object directly, without using expression.